# IOS - Issues with UITextField Inside A Toolbar

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a `UIToolbar` that I have programatically created that has a `UITextField` and `UIButton` added to it as separate subviews.  The code below shows the method which creates the `UIToolbar` and returns the `UIView`.

```
- (UIToolbar *)createToolbar
{
    //set background of toolbar
    UIImage *rawBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbarBackground.png"];
    UIImage *toolBarBackground = [rawBackground stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:22];
    createPostBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    createPostBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);

    [createPostBar setBackgroundImage:toolBarBackground forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //add and syle all toolbar items
    textView = [[HPGrowingTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 6, 270, 40)];
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);

    textView.minNumberOfLines = 1;
    textView.maxNumberOfLines = 6;
    textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
    textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textView.text = @"";
    textView.delegate = self;
    textView.internalTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImage *postBtnBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"postButton.png"];
    UIImage *rawEntryBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"postFieldBackground.png"];
    UIImage *entryBackground = [rawEntryBackground stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:22];

    toolbarOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:entryBackground];
    toolbarOverlay.frame = CGRectMake(4, 0, 278, 44);

    UIButton *postButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [postButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(btnEdit:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [postButton setBackgroundImage:postBtnBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    postButton.frame = CGRectMake(280, 5, 35.0, 35.0);

    [createPostBar addSubview:textView];
    [createPostBar addSubview:toolbarOverlay];
    [createPostBar addSubview:postButton];

    createPostBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    return createPostBar;
}
```

I then add the `UIToolbar` to a `UITextField` as its accessory view when the text field is clicked.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag <= 2)
    {
        textField.inputAccessoryView = [self createToolbar];
    }
}
```

When the text field is clicked the keyboard pops up with the toolbar. Rate now the text field in the toolbar allows you to change the text of the text field that was clicked. Rate now when the text field is clicked the curser stays with in the clicked text field.

How can I make it so that the curser moves to the `UITextField` in the toolbar when the text field is clicked and no the original text field.  Also, how do I disable editing of the text in the text field?  I tried disabling user interactions but that made it so the text field was no longer clickable.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The text fields are supposed to be static the text only changes when the user clicks on the text field, a keyboard opens with a tool bar that allows the user to type in text.  When the user is finished they push the button on the tool bar and it updates the text in the text field. @Wain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using a text field to show your data, use a label instead (with a gesture recognizer).

To show your keyboard, don't use an accessory view, just add the toolbar as a subview and make the text field the first responder.

If you try to do it the way you describe it won't work because the accessory view will be removed when the original text field is no longer the first responder.

Finally, think about maybe using an alert view with a text field instead...

Comment: I will try using labels and let you know if it works.  Also, how exactly do I add subviews to the keyboard view? @Wain

Comment: Don't add the view as a subview of the keyboard. Add it to the same view as the label. Or use the alert view.

Comment: Ok so add it to the bottom of the view and when the keyboard appears it will just push the tool bar up.  When it disappears I can just remove the tool bar correct? @Wain

Comment: The keyboard won't automatically move the toolbar, but you can animate it in (and out). Or the alert view...